# Tail Recursion in Scala return List Head each time after dropping it

Tags: list, scala, recursion

I have a list of users. Each user might have a field users (like friends).
For each user I want to get the users related to that user and return each time the name.
Like some recursive function.

```
case class User(users : List[User])
val users: List[User]
```

For each user I want to get a user name at a time because it would be used to construct something else.

Here is what I tried =>

```
private def helper = {
   users.users.map(u => getName(u))

}
```

this returns a `List[String]` representing userNames

What I want to achieve is to return a single `name: String`, for each user having users at the call of the function until no users are left.

Comment: Are you looking for something like a python "generator"? There is no such concept in scala. But you can just use `foreach`:  `user.users.map(_.getName).foreach { name => println(s"Name is $name") }`. So the "body" of `foreach` (between `{}`) is basically what you would be doing with the output of your "generator"

Comment: exactly something like generator

Comment: No generators in scala. You can use `.map/.flatMap/.foreach` in conjunction with `iterator` or `LazyList`. Or a recursive function, that takes a `process` function as an argument. This gives you effectively the same tools as a generator.

Comment: I think all you want is just `flatMap` instead of `map`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing.

Firstly, I'm not sure what `users.users` is. Is it `user.users` (for `val user: User`) or `users.map(_.users)`? For `val users: List[User]`, `users.users` doesn't compile.

Secondly, I'm not sure what the following means

> What I want to achieve is to return a single `name: String`

If I understood correctly, you have a function

```
def getName(u: User): String = ???
```

and every user has his name and he has his friends having their names. What are you doing transforming many names into a single name?

```
val names: List[String]                = users.map(getName(_))
val friendNames: List[List[String]]    = users.map(_.users.map(getName(_)))
val friendNamesFlattened: List[String] = users.flatMap(_.users.map(getName(_)))
```

Do you want to *return* a single name or *print* the names one by one (one at a time)? If the latter then you just need to add `.foreach`

```
users.flatMap(_.users.map(getName(_))).foreach(println)
```

Or maybe by returning a single name you just meant flattening like with `.flatMap` above. If you already have `val friendNames: List[List[String]]`, you can also do

```
val friendNamesFlattened: List[String] = friendNames.flatten
```

Instead of `.map`/`.flatMap` etc. you can use for-comprehensions

```
val friendNamesFlattened: List[String] =
  for {
    user   <- users
    friend <- user.users
  } yield getName(friend)
```

```
for {
  user   <- users
  friend <- user.users
} println(getName(friend))
```

```
for {
  user   <- users
  friend <- user.users
  name   =  getName(friend)
} println(name)
```

Not sure also what you meant by

> Tail Recursion in Scala return List Head each time after dropping it